# Partial derivative with respect to a function

Tags: partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y,z) = e^{xy^2}$. Find $f_{xxy}$.

How do I start approaching this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your final answer should be $2y^3e^{xy^2}
(2 + xy^2
)$

Comment: I should add that because $f$ is continuously differentiable, it is probably easier to take the two derivatives with respect to x first and get $f(x,y) = y^{4}\cdot e^{x\cdot y^{2}}$. Then it becomes a much simpler problem with no additional work.

Answer (score 3):

$f_{xxy}$ is shorthand for the partial derivative

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f$$

So begin by computing the derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$, using the chain rule; then differentiate twice with respect to $x$.